# On Kotlin jackson ObjectMapper.readValue() causes java.lang.IllegalStateException: readValue(content, jacksonTypeRef<T>()) must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin, jackson

On crashlytics I am getting an `java.lang.IllegalStateException: readValue(content, jacksonTypeRef<T>()) must not be null` exception on the 4th line. I couldn't reproduce it. I think `mapper.readValue(string)`  is returning null where is shouldn't. I handled the string being null case so other than string being null what could cause `mapper.readValue(string)` to return null so I end up with this exception and what is possible way to reproduce this error?

```
var token: token? = null
    get() {
       val string = sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN_KEY, null)
       field = if (string == null) null else mapper.readValue(string)
       return field     
    }
    set(value) {
        field = value
        val json = mapper.writeValueAsString(value)
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(TOKEN_KEY, json).apply()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out `sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN_KEY, null)` is returning "null" string and `mapper.readValue(string)` is returning `null` in this case.